# Dwithin not working on EPSG:4326

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have a layer in GeoServer called "pois". The layer is in EPSG:4326. Also, I have another layer but it is in: EPSG:31256

The problem that I'm having is that I'm trying to reach an all points around coordinates, but when I run query a get dozen of results but not the one point I need.

Here is how my query looks like I'm testing it trough postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=EPSG:4326&typeName=omv_workspace:osm_pois&count=100&cql_filter=dwithin(geom,Point(14.81850 48.77621),500,meters)
```

My query executes but returns bunch of points but not the one I need the closest one to `Point(14.81850 48.77621)`, that one is shown only after I remove count.

Also I passed that point from OpenLayers view in GeoServer but point is not returned.

Comment: Your results are ordered by the primary key, When you limit the count there is no guarantee that the closest point is in the first 10.

Comment: Also 500 degrees is a **long** way so you probably get the whole dataset back. GeoServer and GeoTools do nothing with the units parameter - see https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-4121?jql=project%20in%20(GEOS%2C%20GEOT)%20AND%20text%20~%20dwithin PRs gratefully recieved

Comment: @IanTurton thank you very much for answering, how could I order them bu closest

Comment: Use a projected CRS in metres and all should be well

Comment: Thank you very much again @IanTurton but Im a newbie, could you please explain to me a bit since Im still learning or move me to some article I should read... How do I use projected CRS in metres should I change my CRS on layer or something else ?

Comment: @IanTurton Do you mean I should edit wkt of WGS84 on my geoserver this one: https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/prettywkt/